# Управление длиной видео средствами javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Как при нажатии на кнопку перескочить на 30 секунд видео вперед или назад?
Как зациклить видео до того момента, пока не нажать на определенную кнопку?
Можно ли реализовать подобные манипуляции с помощью javascript? 
Какие библиотеки существуют для таких манипуляций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример на jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/hebabutojo/edit?html,js,output) - по мотивам этого [материала](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2425), в примере показан прогрессбар, но вместо него можно закодить кнопки, да все что угодно.

В примере используется YouTube API, в сети таким примеров масса.